# Why is the mechanical power of a DC brushed motor at a maximum at around 50% of the stall torque?

Tags: power, current, dc-motor, efficiency, brushed-dc-motor

I don't currently fully understand how a DC brushed motor reaches maximum mechanical power at around 50% of their stall torque. I know that a decrease in the speed of the rotor will decrease [back-EMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushless_DC_electric_motor#Controller_implementations) and in turn, increase current, thus the increase in power.

However, I don't exactly understand why the maximum power stops at around 50% of the stall torque. What determines the stop at 50%?

Comment: See http://lancet.mit.edu/motors/motors3.html for useful graphs and details

Comment: It's just another instance of the Maximum Power Transfer theorem at work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_transfer_theorem#:~:text=In%20electrical%20engineering%2C%20the%20maximum,viewed%20from%20its%20output%20terminals.

Comment: Note that this is only true at constant voltage, and the rated voltage is a somewhat artificial limit.  If you really want to get the maximum amount of power out of a motor safely, and you pay close attention to the real limits, then you can get closer to the stall torque at a higher speed.  Assuming a constant voltage is what creates the linear torque-speed curve and that puts the max power at 50%

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because, for a DC motor, the torque curve and speed curve are both linear and of opposite polarity slopes and both curves also start and end at the same place. 100% torque = 0% speed, and 100% speed = 0% torque.

Those two facts mean that the adding them up will always equal 100%. Specifically, 50% of one corresponds to 50% of the other, and since power = torque x RPM, this just happens to be when the multiplication of the two is the maximum.

At one extreme end, you have 100% torque but 0% speed so the multplication gives you zero output power.

At the other extreme end you have 100% speed but 0% torque so the multplication again gives you zero output power.

[image]
Taken from:
https://www.vexforum.com/t/motor-torque-speed-curves/21602

Geometrically, it is identical to why a square is the rectangle with the most area if the sum of all sides is a fixed number. If one side is speed and one side is torque with power being the area, and the sum of length and width must be 100, a square of 50 x 50 gives the most area.