# How can power in a DC motor increase when current decreases?

Tags: power, current, motor, dc, torque

In many graphs for DC motor torque speed power and other characteristics we can clearly see that as the speed of the motor increases the torque decreases, because back emf increases and torque depends on current which is decreased due to the rise of back emf.

But the graph also shows that the power increases with rpm as the current decreases. How is this even possible? It is like we create more power using less energy. That doesn't make sense.

In an internal combustion engine, for example, the more power the engine is producing the more fuel it is using.

Am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: Please include the graph you are referring to.  I assure you the laws of thermodynamics are not being violated.

Comment: Mechanical output power is torque*speed.  So if power increases as torque decreases, speed must be increasing faster than torque decreases.

Comment: I know from a mechanical point of view it doesnt look confusing to me . The problem starts when im using the P=V*I

Comment: Kind of a hand-wavy answer but multiply the current by the efficiency and you'll get the output power curve.  The motor loses efficiency outside of a "sweet spot".

Comment: Even in this case , this means if i go faster in my ev the current is less and the battery drains slower . That doesnt make any sense

Comment: Your EV requires a given amount of torque to move it. Therefore the motor rpm is not at the point of zero torque. The vehicle simply wont accelerate past the point of the torque required and the motor wont get to that part of the graph.

Comment: _"this means if i go faster in my ev the current is less and the battery drains slower"_- that is correct (at the same throttle position = motor voltage). Imagine you are going up a hill, with the motor drawing high current as it fights against gravity. Then you reach the top and start going downhill. You don't throttle back and speed increases. Does current draw increase?  No, it _decreases_ because (as the graph shows) higher rpm = lower current.

Comment: See also "maximum power transfer theorem" to explain the peak in the middle at 50% efficiency. The practical application of all this is, for max efficiency, run a motor fast and lightly loaded, to minimise losses from current and winding resistance.

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/551989/why-is-the-mechanical-power-of-a-dc-brushed-motor-at-a-maximum-at-around-50-of/551992#551992

Comment: You said "Even in this case , this means if i go faster in my ev the current is less and the battery drains slower . That doesnt make any sense." You are right it doesn't make any sense and in fact that is not how it works. Your EV does not hold the voltage fixed at 12 V. It alters the voltage to achieve the speed you want. When you speed up, it increases voltage to make you go faster.

Comment: I would almost suggest you forget you ever saw this graph if you are trying to understand E-bikes or other EV's which operate with a speed controller. This graph is for a motor connected to a fixed voltage, not a motor connected to a speed controller. The speed controller will adjust the voltage which will alter the curve in such a way that the vehicle can be kept closer to the peak efficiency point at all times.

Comment: Power {W} shown is the rate of performing mechanical shaft work. We define this power as shaft torque times angular speed. In SI units torque is Newton-meter {Nm}, shaft speed is radian per second {rad/s}, rad is dimensionless, and special name and symbol for power is Watt {W}. Electrical power is current times voltage. In SI units current is ampere {A}, voltage is volt {V}, and power is Watt {W}. The motor has an air gap that converts input power to output power. If air gap is 100% efficient then input electrical power Pe = Ia x Vbe (armature current times back-emf) equals shaft power output.

Answer (score 2):

Power = Torque * RPM

The plot of RPM is not shown but would be a positive linear slope. (X=Y)
The plot of Torque due to back EMF is a negative linear slope.

The product of the two linear opposing linear slopes starts at zero and ends in zero with a parabolic shape in between.

Answer (score 2):

When the motor is not turning the current is maximum, because there's no back-EMF to oppose the terminal voltage.  All of the energy going into the motor is burnt up in the winding resistance.

As seen in your graph, when the torque * RPM is at its maximum, that's exactly when the power output is maximum.  At that point, the motor is roughly 50% efficient -- which means that for a typical motor, it's getting **hot**.

It's only right at the limit of its RPM range where the efficiency is maximum.  This is analogous to the counter-case for your statement

> In an ic engine for example the more power the engine is producing the more fuel it is using

Unless you start with the throttle wide open and no load on the engine.  Then (assuming it hasn't torn itself apart), if you start loading it mechanically then it'll slow down, pump less air, and consume less fuel (and, possibly, live longer).

Answer (score 1):

I hate these graphs. People look at them and think that they are operational graphs of the motor or something. But they are not. These graphs cover the full range from stalled rotor to overload up to no-load. It is assumed, but not always stated, that the voltage is held fixed. In this case, the input voltage is held at 12 V.

Also, understand that the power shown in the graph is the output power of the motor. It is not the electrical input power. Overloaded motors are not operating in an efficient regime.

What is happening is that in the worst case overload, when the rotor is locked, the mechanical output power of the motor is zero because the shaft speed is zero. Most motors cannot survive indefinitely in this condition. They will overheat and fail somewhere between very fast and fast.

As you gradually release your grip on the shaft and let it spin slowly at first, then faster and faster, the current goes down, the torque goes down, and the speed goes up. Because the speed is going up, the mechanical output power goes up. At some point, the mechanical output power will reach a maximum, then, if you continue to let the shaft speed up, eventually the mechanical output power will start to go down again, and eventually drop to zero when the shaft is spinning freely (zero power because the torque is zero).

Comment: The steady state current and torque do not go to zero for a real system with mechanical damping \$ D > 0 \$ due to sources of friction in the motor and load. This can be seen in the differential equation term when damping  term is not zero there must be an equilibrium torque and equilibrium current to keep the load spinning at constant speed. Of course if it is a position actuator then the servo mechanism must bring input current and output torque to zero to locate the servo at desired position.

Comment: @SystemTheory do you think what you wrote can help the OP or anyone just learning about motors? If I add that to my answer it will just make it harder to understand. Also I never said the current goes to zero, and I would argue that the output torque of an unloaded motor is actually zero. Think of it this way, if I remove my load from the motor shaft altogether, the load is stationary even though the shaft is still spinning. So the torque delivered to the load is zero. If I connect any load to the shaft then the torque will be non zero, agreed.

Comment: The question is how mechanical power increases while current decreases. The short answer is that electrical power is voltage times current, mechanical power is angular shaft speed times torque, and even though the current and torque decay over time the electrical power input exceeds the mechanical power output at any point in time when the device operates as a motor. Further the air gap relations dictate that motor torque is proportional to armature current. One cannot be zero unless the other is zero. There may be zero torque available to drive a load if all torque is used to oppose friction.

Comment: In my opinion, if the portion of the shaft which protrudes from the motor housing is not under torque stress, then the output torque of the motor is zero. Torque at the airgap must be sufficient to overcome friction, but that torque cannot be transmitted to the load. The parasitic drag of the motor causes the output torque to be non-zero. But the power is absorbed inside the motor and is not available to drive a load. Therefore, in my opinion, the output power and torque of a motor which is not connected to a load is always zero.

Comment: The air gap model, provided in my answer, resolves both the original question and enables the critical reasoning about the distinction you are making about zero output torque. When all sinks of torque are accounted for then air gap torque is used to accelerate the inertial load and to overcome rotational damping. If there is no friction then there can be zero current and zero torque at any stead speed in the steady state solution. I may edit the answer to attempt more clarity in how the first law of thermodynamics applies for the battery and brush motor as a first order system.

Comment: @SystemTheory my answer was written for the OP and is an attempt to match the level of understanding that the OP seems to have. My answer is not for you. You understand already perfectly exactly what is going on. But you are trying to tell me to write my answer in a different way. I am sure some people will benefit from your answer because it is detailed and technical. But I am also sure that some people will not be able to understand it at all, and maybe those people will find my answer helpful and more intuitive.

Comment: I am not trying to tell you to write the answer a different way. The initial comment I made is to clarify that torque at any constant speed must be sufficient to overcome the mechanical friction. If the mechanical friction is zero then torque can be zero at that speed for an ideal system. Then since you think my answer is too complicated for a novice or others who are not versed in thermodynamic analysis I only assert that the answer to the question is that electrical power in the air gap is greater than or equal to mechanical power developed at any point in time.

Answer (score 0):

**Revised Answer - Short Answer**

The question is how mechanical power increases while current decreases? Would this violate conservation of energy?

The curves shown in the question eliminate time from the relation of input current to mechanical power output. These curves abstract away from the transient time response of the motor, that is, the startup conditions or dynamic response, in order to give information about the current, torque, speed, and efficiency for any particular motor operating point.

The short answer is that electrical power is voltage times current in the air gap of the motor, the mechanical power is angular shaft speed times torque, and even though the current and torque decay over time the electrical power input equals or exceeds the mechanical power output at any point in time when the device operates as a motor. Power is defined as the derivative of energy, heat, and work with respect to time so the integral of power gives quantities of work, heat, and energy which do not violate the conservation of energy.

**First Law of Thermodynamics**

$$ W = Q + \Delta E $$

In the analysis below the electrical source develops power as current times voltage. This performs electrical work which is the integral of power versus time. This work depletes energy from the electrical source also equal to the area under the power curve versus time. The net result is the increase of kinetic energy associated with the rotor inertia and a quantity of heat lost to the surroundings. The decrease of current and torque during the process do not violate any laws of physics.

**Accounting for Power in the Air Gap**

To eliminate unit conversion factors apply coherent SI units. Then input electrical power and output mechanical power are both specified in SI unit Watt {W}.

This video (11 minutes) shows the air gap equations:

https://youtu.be/GSvoQ4p3qV0

ELECTRICAL SOURCE PARAMETERS:

\$ V_s \$ Source Voltage

\$ R_s \$ Source Resistance

MOTOR PARAMETERS:

\$ R_a \$ Armature Resistance

\$ k_e \$ Back-emf Constant

\$ k_t \$ Torque Constant

\$ J_m \$ Rotor Inertia

\$ B_m \$ Motor Damping

\$ \tau_m \$ Characteristic Time

SYSTEM VARIABLES:

\$ I_a \$ Armature Current

\$ T_m \$ Motor Torque

\$ \omega \$ Shaft Speed

\$ V_e \$ Back-emf Voltage

AIR GAP EQUATIONS:

\$ V_e = k_e \omega \$

\$ T_m = k_t I_a \$

AIR GAP POWER:

\$ P_e = I_a V_e \$

\$ P_m = T_m \omega \$

IDEAL AIR GAP:

\$ P_e = P_m \$

\$ I_a V_e = T_m \omega \$

When the current decreases in the electrical circuit the torque decreases proportionally in the mechanical output. When the shaft speed increases in the mechanical output the back-emf voltage increases proportionally. If the air gap is 100% efficient, meaning there is no thermal power dissipation (armature resistance does not count as air gap loss in this model), then the power developed in the motor as it spins up the rotor inertia and overcomes damping friction is equal to the power developed in the air gap.

**Circuit Simulation**

CIRCUIT MODEL (ZERO MECHANICAL FRICTION)

[image]

SKETCH OF POWER INPUT/OUTPUT TIME RESPONSE

[image]

If the motor accelerates up to maximum speed under no load conditions when the source provides a step voltage input then the power output from the source is shown by an exponential decay curve and the total energy depletion from the source is the area under this curve. The mechanical power developed to accelerate the rotor inertia up to speed is shown by the second curve with a "hump" shape. The area under this curve equals the change in kinetic energy of the rotor inertia as a function of time. This area is shown as \$ \Delta E \$. The difference between the energy output of the battery and the energy increase of the mechanical system is the area between the two curves shown as heat \$ Q \$. There is no mechanical damping in this simplified model so the heat is lost in the source resistance and armature resistance.